# Exporting Project To Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2015, export

im trying to export this C++ SMFL Project im working on Visual Studio to a partner. But my partner runs on a Ubuntu Mate(Linux Distro). Currently when i just copy the project folder from Documents/VisualStudio2015/[PRPOJECTNAME]  It dosent work for him. He describes it as "It Dosent Do Anything" - Partner . Is there a fix for this? Or are you unable to ship Visual Studio C++ Projects to partner. BTW, i am running a Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. My OS Is Windows 10.

Comment: if you wrote the program in standard C++ then your source files should work on linux, maybe some modifications are required. But usually you have to define the project settings explicitly based on the compiler/IDE your partner is using on Ubuntu. To my knowledge the Visual Studio project file isn't supported under linux.

Comment: @andreaplanet wrote in Plain C++ . + SFML Is Cross Platform

Comment: The Visual Studio project file, containing the list of c++ files, compiler options, linker options, libraries, etc, is not supported on Linux. You must specify those options differently, it depends on which compiler/IDE your partner is using. With simple projects a one line command could be enough, for example g++ myfile1.cpp myfile2.cpp ...

Comment: @andreaplanet how do i export my project as a .exe file?

Comment: @andreaplanet i also have codeblocks... Will that help?

Comment: exe files normally doesn't run under linux. You must give him the whole source code and he must compile the program. Or you install linux on on a virtual machine on your computer and you compile it for him.

Comment: Suprisingly i do have a virtual machine... But how would i compile it @andreaplanet

Comment: Do i just install codeblocks on my kali @andreaplanet ?

Comment: Since you know it, you could install codeblocks on your virtual machine. To make it easy install the same Ubuntu version your partner has.

Comment: Ok @andreaplanet i will do that. Thankyou for your advice sir

Comment: Note: For crossplatform development i prefer the open source Qt Creator IDE. You can copy & paste your project folder and just rebuild it as is.

Comment: Wait @andreaplanet if i work on QT Creator IDE on windows.. can i send to linux?

Comment: you must still compile on linux if you want to send the binary only. But if you want to send the whole source project then you just have to copy the project folder to linux and compile it there with Qt Creator (need to install it)